# IIS works fine with IP but fails externally with name

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, iis-7.5

I can access my application with no problems via the IP https://12.xxx.xx.xx/test.aspx; however, when I try to access this via the domain https://test.domain.com I come up with the very common "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found." which leads me to think something is wrong with my web.config, but seeing as I can get to the resource fine via the IP I am starting to think something else is going on with IIS. Suggestions?

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: Running IIS version 7.5  on windows 2008 r2

Comment: can you modify the web.config value customErrors?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684665.aspx

Comment: so it turns out I just needed a refresh of the DNS for this thing to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your IIS logs to find out which HTTP status code is actually being thrown.